# Can someone explain this Javascript code/ challenge?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, while-loop

I am taking some online classes on Javascript and I came across this challenge. Long story short, the result of the challenge is the code below. Although I got the code correctly, I have no idea what's going on inside the while loop.

```
     var html = '';
      var red;
      var green;
      var blue;
      var rgbColor;

      var counter = 0;

      while (counter <10) {

      red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
      green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
      blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
      rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
      html += '<div style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '"></div>';

      counter +=1;
    }


 document.write(html);
```

I would put a link to the code, but Jsfiddle doesn't allow me using document.write. The result is 10 colored circles which change colors every time I refresh the page.

My questions would be:

- how come we have 10 divs on the page and none in the html code?
- why did we multiply Math.random by 256?
- what's the meaning of these two lines of code?

  ```
     rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
     html += '<div style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '"></div>';
  ```

I see strings and numbers concatenations which I didn't know they are even possible.

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for professional and enthusiast programming questions. This question appears to be asking us to teach you the fundamentals of JavaScript. I recommend spending more time researching the language and educating yourself, as I can't see any reasonable way to answer this question without having you learn the language as a baseline.

Comment: To use it in a JSFiddle, use `document.body.innerHTML = html;` instead of `document.write()`

Comment: [rgb(RED,GREEN, BLUE) colors, expressed as numeric values.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp) hope it gives you an idea... of the 10 iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code starts out by declaring variables

```
var html = '';
var red;
var green;
var blue;
var rgbColor;
var counter = 0;
```

The `html` variable is initialized to an empty string. And the counter variable is initialized to the number value of zero

We then go into a while loop

```
while (counter <10) {
```

While the counter is LESS than 10, keep looping.

At the end of the code block we have

```
counter +=1;
```

The `+=` notation is short hand for take the current value of the variable and add to it the stuff on the right side. It is equivalent to `counter = counter + 1`. Since we start `0` we will loop 10 times. We can count below that the condition is true 10 times and exits in the case of `10<10`

```
while (0 <10) TRUE
while (1 <10) TRUE
while (2 <10) TRUE
while (3 <10) TRUE
while (4 <10) TRUE
while (5 <10) TRUE
while (6 <10) TRUE
while (7 <10) TRUE
while (8 <10) TRUE
while (9 <10) TRUE
while (10 <10) FALSE
```

[Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number between 0(inclusive) and 1(exclusive). Multiplying it by 256 and taking the [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) will return a number between 0 and 255. We had to do 256 since the 1 in the random generator is exclusive and not included in the result. So the following lines set red,green,blue to a number between 0 and 255.

```
red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
```

Since this code block is in the while loop it will be set to a random number each iteration.

In javascript the overloaded `+` operator can do different things depending on the operand. In the case of `string + number` it will concatenate the number onto the string

```
rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
```

As we said before red,green, and blue will be a random number between 0 and 255. So the concatenation will look something like this:

```
rgbColor = 'rgb(' + 45 + ',' + 156 + ',' + 34 + ')';
```

which all combined will be the string:

```
rgbColor = 'rgb(45,156,34)';
```

This line is an example of `+=` again, so it is taking the value of html and adding another string to it

```
html += '<div style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '"></div>';
```

Which given our previous values will turn into this:

```
html += '<div style="background-color:rgb(45,156,34)"></div>';
```

This creates a string that has HTML markup with a div that sets the [background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) css property to our random color. Given that we initialized the `html` vairable before the loop and we are using `+=` to build up the string it will a string with 10 div elements all with random colors.

[document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) writes to the open document stream, that is when the page is first getting rendered. The main concern here is that if we call `document.write` after the page is loaded it will clear the document

```
document.write(html);
```

When this line is hit the loop has been executed and we have the string `html` that now has 10 div elements with random background color. This string gets written to the document. Viewing the rendered source will show these div elements.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the very detailed explanation :-). My biggest issue was to understand how we were able to make colors out of three numbers, since this step wasn't explained in the lesson I took.

Answer (score 3):

- `rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';` creates a string that represents the rgb value that was randomly generated during that iteration in the loop.
- Each time the loop runs, `html += '<div style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '"></div>';` adds a circle div into a variable.
- After you get outside the loop, `document.write(html);` writes all of the circle divs you generated (there were 10 total because the loop runs 10 times) onto the page, making them visible.
- You multiply by 256 because `Math.random` generates something between 0 and 1. Then, the `floor()` method truncates the decimal portion off, leaving you with an integer between 0 and 256. RGB values are made up of 3 values from 0 to 256.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Yes, now it's clear. You were on point :-). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

1. You have a while loop that runs for 10 times generating 10 divs for you, how it does is that it creates an html code for how a div looks like.
2. Math.random() generates a random number between 0 and 1, multiplication with 256 will convert the number to color code, colors in computer are represented using 6 digit hex codes i.e. FFFFFF where first FF represents portion of red, second ff represent portion of green and third FF represents green. FFFFFF is white and 000000 is black.
3. `rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')'` is a color representation syntax of html.

10 divs appear on the page only when you do a document.write(html);

so at end of the loop your code will have 10 divs appended to each other to make valid HTML code.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. The most confusing part was obtaining a color out of three randomly generated numbers. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is simple as that:

```
//These are variables you're declaring
var html = ''; // empty string
var red;
var green;
var blue;
var rgbColor;
var counter = 0; // number 0
//While the value of counter is less then 10 continue looping
while (counter <10) {
      //Here are 3 colors represents RED, GREEN BLUE, Math.random returns a float number from 0 to 1
      red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
      green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
      blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
      //After calculating the colors we concat it to a string with RGB properties
      rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
      //Then create the html the div
      html += '<div style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '"></div>';

      counter +=1;
    }
//And then render the code transforming into html
document.write(html);
```

The Html is rendered with write if you take a look at the source code after the execution you'll see those divs that were in html rendered inside the document. The thing is creating 10 circles, playing with RGB bit colors randomly, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, now things are definitely more clear. I found it very confusing that you can generate numbers and by combining them you will end up displaying colors :).

Comment: In my opinion @CasiaHospi, if you have never programmed you could start with some simple cases first like statements how to declare variables and etc. I like this one to learn how to program: https://www.codecademy.com

Comment: I actually know about statements, variable, functions and loops :). Let's just say the the lessons I take use code examples that we didn't learn about yet (this representation of a color using three numbers was just an example Although I know what RGB values are, I didn't know you can obtain them with JS like that) .

Answer (score 1):

2. RGB is a color model that allow to represent a color. It's composed by three values R, G, B ranging from 0 to 256. When you multiply Math.random by 256 you obtain a value in this interval (Math.random generates a values between 0 and 1, multiply by 256 -> random value between 0 and 256). You do this for Red, Blue and Green and get a random color.
3. You put together the three generated values (red, blue and green) and obtain a random color.

Example :

rgb(248, 248, 8)  -> yellow

More info : [w3schools - HTML colors](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp)

Comment: Now it makes total sense. Thank you for your help.